# Given difference of two RV draws, what is the new expectation of each individual draw?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

We have two draws, $d1$ and $d2$, from a known distribution $F()$. Provided that we know $d1-d2$, can we update our expectations/distribution for an individual draw? That is, what are:

$ E[d1|d1-d2=k] $

$ f(d1|d1-d2=k) $

Thanks!

Comment: $f(d_1=x|d_1-d_2=k)=\frac{f(x,x-k)}{\int f(x,x-k)\, dx}=\frac {f(x)f(x-k)}{\int f(x)f(x-k)\, dx}$

Comment: Ah, a silly question... Thanks for taking the time!